React Router SSR: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component
I followed this guide https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/ssr#without-a-data-router
I'm server rendering an app like this
<StaticRouter location={req.url}>
  <Routes>
    // ...
  </Routes>
</StaticRouter>


One of my routes includes this code
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router'

export function SceneButton(props: SceneButtonProps) {
  const location = useLocation()
  // ...
  return <button>Scene</button>
}


When I render the app I get this error
useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

How do I get the location here in a way that works both browser and server-side?
Also, weirdly the React Router docs really want me to use Remix, but my app is large and I can't afford to rewrite it.

If you are using StaticRouter from react-router-dom/server
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";

then I suspect you need to also import the useLocation hook from the same library, e.g. react-router-dom instead of the lower-level react-router library.
Update SceneButton to import from react-router-dom:
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export function SceneButton(props: SceneButtonProps) {
  const location = useLocation();
  // ...
  return <button>Scene</button>;
}

React-Router-DOM re-exports all of React-Router, so there's no need to include both as project dependencies. If you have both then I suggest removing react-router from the project:
npm uninstall react-router

Thanks Drew! Solved by importing everything from 'react-router-dom'
